# Creating 2vs2 room with friends in Unity with PUN

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I would like to create a game mode 2vs2 with our friends. I have no idea where to start off. How can we send them notification regarding some of our friends is looking for party. I think this is probably we would have to take care of through push notification from our server and then once other player joins the room how can we create room properties so that both of us remain in the same team. Do we need to create a private room in that case or what ?

Answer (score 0):

When working with PUN and Photon Cloud, you need to connect to a master server first (PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings). Then create a room or join existing. PhotonNetwork.JoinOrCreateRoom should work in your case. Players should share same room name before creation or joining a room. Notify them outside Photon by any means you like. 
Inside a room, player custom properties can be used to mark which team player belongs to. Assets\Photon Unity Networking\UtilityScripts\PunTeams.cs script goes with PUN package. Use it as is or as a template for your own teams implementation.
Don't forget set max player = 4 when creating a room to prevent extra players getting into room if more than 4 player know its name or via room matchmaking.
Follow doc.photonengine.com for more info, documentations and tutorials.